# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when trying to rename files

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

I am trying to rename newly created converted jpgs using Python but every time I go to rename the file I get the error that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Even if I close the opened image in the first for loop of the function I still get this error.  What do I need to do differently to make this work? Below is my code:

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import shutil

def convert_image_to_jpeg(directory, newImagePath, upc):
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            imagePath = os.path.join(root, file)
            charstrip = imagePath
            charstrip = charstrip[charstrip.rindex('.')+1:]
            charcount = len(charstrip)
            newFilePath = imagePath[:-charcount] + 'jpg'
            originalImage = Image.open(imagePath)
            originalImage_rgb = originalImage.convert('RGB')
            originalImage_rgb.save(newFilePath)
            shutil.move(newFilePath, newImagePath)
    
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(newImagePath):
        for a in files:
            b = a.split('_')
            c = b[1]
            print(c)
            newFileNamePrefix = upc + '_A'
            print(newFileNamePrefix)
            newFileName = newFileNamePrefix + c
            print(newFileName)
            renamedImagePath = os.path.join(root, newFileName)
            print(renamedImagePath)            
            os.rename(newImagePath, renamedImagePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  I wasn't providing the os.rename method with the complete path of the original image to be renamed.  The new and working code looks like this:

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import shutil

def convert_image_to_jpeg(directory, newImagePath, upc):
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            imagePath = os.path.join(root, file)
            charstrip = imagePath
            charstrip = charstrip[charstrip.rindex('.')+1:]
            charcount = len(charstrip)
            newFilePath = imagePath[:-charcount] + 'jpg'
            originalImage = Image.open(imagePath)
            originalImage_rgb = originalImage.convert('RGB')
            originalImage_rgb.save(newFilePath)
            originalImage.close()
            shutil.move(newFilePath, newImagePath)
    
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(newImagePath):
        for a in files:
            jpegImagePath = os.path.join(root, a)
            b = a.split('_')
            c = b[1]
            print(c)
            newFileNamePrefix = upc + _A'
            print(newFileNamePrefix)
            newFileName = newFileNamePrefix + c
            print(newFileName)
            renamedImagePath = os.path.join(root, newFileName)
            print(renamedImagePath)            
            os.rename(jpegImagePath, renamedImagePath)
```